# paper - abstract - manually change the date

Tags: datetime, abstract

In my paper I have a sole page for the abstract. There I state the title of my paper, my name and the abstract. However, it marks also the date. As it marks the actual (today) date, I'd like to know how I can manually change the date thereby.

I copy the header of my latex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{hanging}

\geometry{left=1.4in,right=1.0in,top=1.4in,bottom=1.2in}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{bla bla bla} 
\author{bla bla bla}
\maketitle
\onehalfspacing
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
\noindent In this study, we contribute to ..... \\[10pt]


\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: add `\date{}` before `\maketitle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample code. As Asis said in the comment, you just need to add the `\date{}` command.

## Example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}


\title{Test}
\author{Joe Schmoe}
\date{March 1, 2015} % \today = date from system clock
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}


\end{document}
```

---

Also useful is the [`datetime2` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2?lang=en). With this you can customize the date. Based on your writing, I will guess that you speak German, so I suppose the following might help *(even if I am wrong, the chances that this will help you are still high I think :)*:

```
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy,yearmonthsep=.,monthdaysep=.,dayyearsep=.]{datetime2}
\usepackage[yearmonthsep=/,monthdaysep=/,dayyearsep=/]{datetime2}
```

Or the [`datetime` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime):

```
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\renewcommand\dateseparator{.}
```

I grew up with mm/dd/yyyy, but even I find it ridiculous to start with the month. [Here is a list of countries using dd.mm.yyyy format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country):

```
% Countries using the dd.mm.yyyy variant:
Armenia
Azerbaijan
Basque Country
Belarus
Bulgaria
Estonia
Finland
Georgia
Germany
Greenland
Iceland
Kazakhstan
Kyrgyzstan
Latvia
Liechtenstein
Macedonia
Montenegro
Norway
Poland
Romania
Russia
Serbia
Slovakia
Slovenia
Switzerland
Turkey
Turkmenistan
Ukraine
Uzbekistan

% Countries also using the ddmmyyyy order:
Same Order, diff format:
Nepal
Netherlands
Portugal
Spain
United Kingdom
```

Comment: Tried it out, works perfectly! thank you very much!!